# Slack Notifications Not Working in Laravel 8 Production Environment

Tags: php, laravel

Slack notifications are working normally in my local `app.test` environment but not working in production.  I've been working on this for hours and can't figure it out.

**This is my configuration:**

PHP 7.4, Laravel 8.12, Slack Notification Channel package, Channel 2.3, [Envoyer.io](https://envoyer.io/), [Forge](https://forge.laravel.com/)

**logging.php**

```
...
'channels' => [
        'stack' => [
            'driver' => 'stack',
            'channels' => ['slack','single'],
            'ignore_exceptions' => false,
        ],
        'slack' => [
            'driver' => 'slack',
            'url' => env('LOG_SLACK_WEBHOOK_URL'),
            'username' => 'Laravel Log',
            'emoji' => ':boom:',
            'level' => env('LOG_LEVEL', 'critical'),
        ],
...
```

**.env on Envoyer.io**

```
...
LOG_CHANNEL=slack
LOG_SLACK_WEBHOOK_URL=https://hooks.slack.com/services/T0XXXXXXXXX/myapicodexxxxxxxxxxxx
...
```

I've tried `php artisan config:clear` `php artisan config:cache` `php artisan queue:restart`, but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Could be so many things. Is your production `LOG_LEVEL` not set, or higher than the logs being triggered? Are you SURE you edited the right environment? Did Envoyer properly deploy the env variables?

Comment: We'll need a bit more to go on. What debugging have you done so far? Have your tried creating a single page that just creates a log notification and outputs the result? Have you checked the logs, and if so is anything in there? What level is the log that you're triggering? What is `LOG_LEVEL` set to? Have you tried dumping `LOG_LEVEL` to ensure it's correct?

Comment: @AkenRoberts Not specifying the `LOG_LEVEL` was the issue.

Comment: Did you run the queue worker? Do you get an error?